# Stagger Repeated Dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make an attendance and time sheet for my team at work. However, we only work on MWF. How can I autofill dates in a row but skip weekends?

Have been looking at the WORKDAY function.

I successfully have GSheets repeat every other day, but I need to skip dates that fall on Sunday.

Current:
(01/07, 01/09, 01/11, 01/13, 01/15)

Expected:
(01/07, 01/09, 01/11, 01/15)

Comment: If we're talking about 2019, then 01/15 is a Tuesday. Could this possibly have been a typo and perhaps you meant `01/07,01/09, 01/11, 01/14, 01/16, 01/18, 01/21, etc ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of discussion, we'll assume the dates are in column A.

Enter the first three dates manually.
Then for the fourth date use `=DATEVALUE(A1) +7`.
Then copy the fourth cell down as far as you need.

Credit: [Bob Umlas, Excel MVP](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/fill-date-series-with-mondaywednesdayfriday-only/63ed38de-d317-47c6-8290-75f0831128c0)

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(WORKDAY("6/1/2019", {1; 3; 5; 7}))
```

[image: 6]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Both of these solutions are great.

Comment: @player0 Ingenious use of an array. If you wanted to fill in, say, a range of 10 rows, would you need to express each value in the array (which might be tedious), or do you think there some alternative to use ArrayConstrain/ArrayFormula to "auto-populate" the range?

Comment: @Tedinoz in this formula form yes, you would need to express each

Answer (score 0):

With a Monday date in A1, in A2 and dragged *across* to suit:

```
=A1+if(weekday(A1)<>6,2,4)
```

should create a series of successive Monday, Wednesday and Friday dates.